# External IP is showing as pending

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and trying to deploy my first application. I have created a deployment and service for my app, but I am not able to access it from outside the cluster. When I run kubectl get svc, the EXTERNAL-IP is showing as `<pending>`. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

How to resolve External IP issue.

Comment: can you give more context about your k8s environment?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Service of type LoadBalancer you need external infrastructure to provide the IP, therefore the state is shown as `pending`.

If you use minikube for the cluster you can use `minikube tunnel` to provide the IP, which will be accessible from your machine.

For on-premises clusters there are solutions like MetalLB https://metallb.universe.tf/

The other option is to use a Service of type NodePort and use the assigned port (usually one in the range above 31000) and any IP of a node of the cluster. You can query them using `kubectl get nodes -o wide`

Comment: this should be a comment to the question not an answer